# Verb Phrase ellipsis in the subordinate

Tags: verbs, ellipsis, subordinate-clauses

Larson (1987) shows the following as well-formed:

(1) b. ii. I will have lived every place that John **has lived**.

I just wondered if the next example would be better formed.

- I will have lived every place that John **has**.

[Larson, R. K. (1987). " Missing prepositions" and the analysis of English free relative clauses. Linguistic inquiry, 18(2), 239-266.]

Comment: I don't see the relevance of 'free relative clauses' to your examples.

Comment: Oh, the title does not bear any relevance to my inquiry. This is separate from the paper's content.

Comment: "Deleting" the predictably repeated ***lived*** from your second example isn't inherently "better formed" - it's just an alternative ***stylistic choice*** that we often make.

Comment: People **live in** places rather than just **live** them. The only direct object that usually follows **live** is **life**.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Which would you personally choose if forced to do so? I'd for one select the second one.

Comment: Well, if you already have a preference, why are you asking about it here in theb first place? But I disagree with your thinking *on principle*. For example, I'm pretty sure the chances of me repeating the verb *(**lived**)* in the cited context would be higher if I wanted to focus more on the fact that ***John*** has lived (or *will* have lived, that's ambiguous) in all of those places, not the fact that at some point in the future I will have done the same. To repeat myself, your second example definitely ***isn't*** inherently "better formed".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica I asked you simply because I am an L2 speaker and wanted to know how L1 speakers look on the sentences. Repetition is oftentimes not liked particularly in English; I wondered if this applied here too. Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Perhaps I overreacted against the specific expression "better formed" there. There's absolutely no doubt in my mind that in the vast majority of contexts, discarding that *potential* verb repetition is far more ***likely*** - which in practice is mostly what matters to you. But you should note that a competent writer / speaker might well decide not to adopt the majority choice in some specific context, and it wouldn't be a good idea for you to be thinking "I know English better than this guy!"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica In cases like that, I always think there should be some implicature meant. That he/she must have repeated it purposely as rhetorical mean. It's always a part of my learning process.

Comment: I've only just noticed the matter of that "missing preposition". And I have to admit I have absolutely no idea why it seems perfectly okay to "discard" the preposition in your *exact* example, this doesn't seem to apply with a different "location" noun: *I will have lived **in every town** that John has [lived **in**]*. Is that why Larson gives that specific example? Does he explicitly recognise that at least *some* nouns ***require*** a preposition in such contexts?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I'm slow. I had to get over with lots of university errands. Sorry. You may not notice my comment any more, but I'll write back anyway. The paper I'm reading tries to analyze exactly how and why some NPs can miss their partner preposition and some can't. In a nutshell, he had recourse to a unique syntactic feature of a certain noun, exact overt and tangible existence of whom uncovered, that could go down to a longer NP that has the noun as the head and stand valid.

Comment: He assessed nouns that fall in that category can stay in the adjunct position, as in the D-structure, because, if no Case is given, it provides itself with Oblique Case, the default Case, of itself. Hence, you don't need the missing preposition. However, there appear to be a handful of contradictions with  Case theory and θ Criterion subdivisions.

Comment: I should have put it in the plural. --- a unique syntactic feature of a certain noun >>> a unique syntactic feature of certain nouns. Too late, the five minutes has lapsed.